# Unable to load data into snowflake table using Python

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-ec2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a pandas data frame with 15K records. I am running my code in EC2 instance via PuTTY. I want to load the dataframe in snowflake table. I am using pd_writer option from to_sql but getting segmentation fault. Even I tried to insert just 5 records still I got same error.

I have done some calculations in Python and result is stored in a data frame.
Now I am using below piece of code to load data in snowflake via EC2 connection with snowflake is done using key pair authentication and same connection is used before to fetch data from snowflake to Python

```
df.to_sql(cust_table, eng,index=False, method=pd_writer)
```

Here, `eng` is `sqlalchemy.engine.Engine`.

I have also used below method but got the same segmentation fault error.

```
write_pandas(ctx,df,cust_table)
```

Here, `ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(...)`.

Comment: Are you able to show a complete example? The snippet of code that you have provided is not really enough to figure out what is going on since it cannot be run on its own.

Comment: @SimonD- Code is in virtual environment and it belongs to client so can't produce full code, however same code when I run at my machine I was able to load the to snowflake but when I run the code in EC2 I got the segmentation fault error even for transferring 10 records